# Object Lock issue in DB using stored procedure

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement, ibm-midrange

I have a process which loads data from a file and then tries to insert the records in a table.

If the file is too large, it takes a while to load all the data in the XYZ table. I am using batch to insert the records in the table.

In the meantime, another process kicks in and tries to read data based on some condition from the XYZ table, since the 1'st process hasn't finished writing the data to the table and the 2'nd process tries to read the same data, I get an Object in use error.

I was thinking of two options to fix this issue:

1. Unless all the records are inserted by process1, keep one of the status column different, so that process2 can't retreive the records
2. Insert the data in chunks, if something fails, have a mechanism to retry from the last record inserted (need a mechanism for this).

I am using DB2 and plain jdbc to insert records.

Please let me know whats the best possible way to go about for this issue

Comment: Another option is to do all inserts in one transaction, that way others won't see the inserts until your loading process is finished. Btw: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using DB2 and I am using plain jdbc for inserting records in DB

Answer (score 1):

V4.5 is an antique, but even way back then, most normal DB operations do not require an exclusive lock on the file.  I'm very surprised to hear that there's an object lock involved here.

I'd suggest modifying the IBM side just a bit.  Continue to use JDBC to load the rows into the DB2 table as happens now, but when the bulk load is done, load one row into a new table.  This row in the new table is what will trigger the IBM process to go process the completely loaded original table.  The IBM admin can use a trigger on the new table to get notified that a new record has arrived.

If it is impossible to modify the IBM side, consider loading up a temporary table and then using [JT400](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) to issue a CPYF command to have the IBM OS copy the rows into the real table.  That should run much faster than over the network.  Or, rename it from TEMPFILE to REALFILE, but the IBM process might not like that.

Comment: I wrote a sample program to prove that DB Operations acquires an exclusive lock on the file. Its not possible for me to modify the IBM side. I was thinking of introducing one more column in the table and  populating with some value say "N" and updating this value to Y, once all the rows has been inserted in the table. The other process will pick only the rows with the data in new column as "Y". It should work this way. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: We may have a terminology issue.  On OS/400, an exclusive lock means that no other process on the system can even look at your table.  You can tell what lock you have via the OS400 command WRKOBJLCK.  If you cannot modify the IBM side, how will you be allowed to add a column?

Comment: Forgive me for the misunderstanding.Yes I can modify the table, if need be.

Comment: I can't see how a new column resolves the second process throwing an 'Object in use' error.

Comment: The second process won't pick those rows which are inserted at the same time by first process as a result it would avoid the File in Use error

Comment: The second process would need to read the rows to determine Y/N.  How can that happen without using the file?

Comment: The isolation level Cursor stability (CS)  prevents an application from reading any row that was changed by other applications until the change was committed. It doesn't try to  read the whole file but rows in the file which matches its criteria. So the new column would prevent the process 2 from reading those rows which are inserted by process1, but not yet committed.

Comment: CS won't throw an 'Object in use' error.  Either the description of the problem is not accurate or there is something else happening that has not yet been described.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38914/discussion-between-abs-and-buck-calabro)

Comment: If the index is old enough, the whole index can be locked. Attributes should be checked to see if the index is ACCPTHSIZ(*MAX1TB). If it's the older ACCPTHSIZ(*MAX4GB), the index should be recreated. (Unlikely with any reasonably new index, but possible if it's been around for years.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what DB or libraries you are using but you should look at using transactions to control the simultaneous reading and writing. Process 1 should write chunk of data in a single transaction. None of this data will be visible to process 2 until it has all been written so you shouldn't get any conflicts between the two. This is assuming that you have the correct transaction isolation level set up on the data.

If you are using Spring, for example, then it is easy to mark a function with @Transactional so that all the DB calls in tat function operate in a single transaction.

Comment: I am using one transaction to insert everything, since the data is so large, it somehow ends up locking the whole file i.e table, as a result when the next scheduled process runs, it cant retrieve anything from that table, bcz the system says the file is in use.

Comment: @Abs: are you saying that the high number of inserts results in a table lock in DB2? That's pretty lame. Which DB2 version is that? I thought in newer versions readers would never be blocked by writers.

Comment: I am using Db2 iseries v4.5 .

Comment: What percentage of records are you inserting? What isolation level is each process using?  Are both processes referring to a physical file (table), or is there a logical file or index involved?

Comment: @WarrenT: I am inserting 100,000 records. The isolation leve is Read committed. Both the processes are referring to physical file.

Comment: Does the physical have a keyed access path?  You are inserting 100k rcds, but roughly how many rcds are in the file beforehand?